# Overwrite bindings in rabbitmq

Tags: migration, rabbitmq

I'm attempting to streamline our rabbitmq migrations and as part of this using broker definitions in version control.

Ultimately I'd like to have a roll forward and roll backward script I can run to change queues, bindings and exchanges in production.

Currently if the bindings change, I am uploading a broker definitions file with the new bindings, which unfortunately preserves the existing bindings alongside.

So then I run a script using multiple rabbitmqadmin delete commands.

This is a little cumbersome however - what would be ideal is if in the broker definitions file, some flag could be set to ensure that when the new bindings have been added, the old bindings are deleted automatically.

Does anyone know of some feature like this? Or a superior technique? Or some library in some scripting language that is designed for this?

Comment: When you update the new bindings do you need to persist existing queues/messages? If not, you can try the `rabbitmqctl reset` command

Comment: Yes, ideally I need the other queues, bindings, exchanges and message that aren't relevant to the deploy to remain unaffected. Otherwise, reset would be ok if we had failover rabbits.